# urls.py - redirect the / page to another app

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

For two days now i`m trying to redirect the root page '/' to another urls.py

After reading how to do it i wrote this :

```
url(r'^$', indlude('x.y.urls')),
```

and this is my x.y.core urls.py :

```
url(r'^$', IndexPageView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

but I get 404 error.

I tried a lot off stuff like :

```
url(r'', indlude('x.y.urls'))

url(r'^$/', indlude('x.y.urls'))
```

and in x.y.urls :

```
url(r'^$', IndexPageView.as_view(), name='index'),
url(r'', IndexPageView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

The only way to make it work is this :

```
url(r'^$', IndexPageView.as_view()),
```

Any idea how to make it work ? If I redirect '/' to the IndexPageView directly everything works so views and templates are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

project.urls pattern

```
url(r'^', include('some_app.urls', namespace='some_app')),
```

some_app.urls patterns

```
url(r'^$', IndexPageView.as_view(), name='index'),
url(r'^other/view/$', OtherView.as_view(), name='other_view'),
```

---

And for example what may be inside IndexPageView

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class IndexPageView(RedirectView):
    permanent = False

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user is not None and self.request.user.is_superuser:
            return reverse('some_app:other_view')
        else:
            return '/accounts/login/'
```